# Poetry fails to find a compatible version for the very first added package (numpy)

Tags: python, python-poetry

I initialized a poetry project. It generated the configuration:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "projectname"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["My Name <my@email.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Right after that, I launched

```
poetry add numpy
```

And it returned

```
Using version ^1.25.1 for numpy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.0s)

The current project's Python requirement (>=3.8,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
  - numpy requires Python >=3.9, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.8,<3.9

Because no versions of numpy match >1.25.1,<2.0.0
 and numpy (1.25.1) requires Python >=3.9, numpy is forbidden.
So, because janesweather depends on numpy (^1.25.1), version solving failed.

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For numpy, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.9,<4.0"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers
```

Why is poetry not able to find a compatible version of numpy?

I tried with `python = ">=3.8,<3.9"` but it failed the same. I tried to specify a version, e.g., `poetry add numpy==1.24.1`, which worked. But I assume poetry should be able to find a compatible version by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [tool.poetry.dependencies] python = "^3.8"

^3.8 implies your package HAS to be compatible with ALL python versions between 3.8 and 4.

> poetry add numpy

tries to intall the LATEST version of numpy available (1.25.1), but that isn't compatible with python 3.8

Edit -- for what you're after (per comments) try

> poetry add numpy@*

HTH

Comment: As mentioned, I also tried with ">=3.8,<3.9" and it still picked version 1.25.1.

Comment: per above, the version you specify against python has no bearing on the numpy version

Comment: Does it mean I have to specify manually the version number when the latest version of a package is not compatible with the Python version specified? I thought poetry was supposed to resolve dependencies and add packages that are compatible. Is it not possible to have poetry find by itself the latest numpy version that is compatible (I know it exists because when I manually specify version 1.24.1, it works)?

Comment: ok, now I understand what you're after :) try 


poetry add numpy@*

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! Write it as an answer and I will accept it as solution.
Here is the documentation about @, which does not even mention this trick:
https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-the--operator

I do not understand why this is not the default behavior. I am also not sure whether this is needed all the time for poetry to check compatibility with all installed packages (those added previously with "poetry add"), or just when there is a compatibility issue with Python itself.

Comment: With numpy@*, I see that poetry puts ```numpy = "*"``` in pyproject.toml, which is not a specified version. This does not help to get a consistent installation in different clones of the project.